# Angular 2 http Post failing on client side but data is getting inserted in the Database

Tags: http, angular

**Service**

The HTTP post service

```js
addUser(body: Object): Observable<any> {
    let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/v3/user/Adduser', body, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); 
}
```

**Component**

When I call this method, the data is getting inserted into the database, but I am unable to get the response. It is going into the error block. Please look at the image below for error information.

```js
addUser(items: any) {
    this.signupService.addUser(items)
        .subscribe(response => {
            this.eventsEmitter.broadcast('Success', 'Changes Saved Succesfully');
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        },
        error => {
            debugger;
            this.eventsEmitter.broadcast('Error', 'Error Occured');
        });
}
```

**Error Information**

[image: error]

Not sure how to resolve this. Can you please tell me the changes to make it work?

**Web API Controller**

This is the web API controller

```js
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddUser")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddUser([FromBody]UsersModel model)
{
    try
    {
        await _userService.AddUser(model);
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        return ResponseMessage(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do the following changes :

```
addUser(items: any) {
            this.signupService.addUser(items)
                .subscribe(response => {
                    this.eventsEmitter.broadcast('Success', 'Changes Saved Succesfully');
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                });
        }
```

Web API Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("AddUser")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddUser([FromBody]UsersModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                await _userService.AddUser(model);
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                return ResponseMessage(response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return InternalServerError(ex);
            }
        }
```

Http Service :

```
 addUser(body: Object): Observable<any> {
            let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body);
            let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

            return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/v3/user/Adduser', body, options)
                .map((response : Response) => {
            if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
                throw new Error('This request has failed ' + response.status);
            }
            else {
                return response.json();
            }
        });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import the necessary dependencies:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```